# List of the new WP7 APIs in Mango Update?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Does anyone know where we can get a list of the new API's that will be released in with the Mango Update? According to the keynote there supposed to be about 1500. Also I think it was next month, but does anyone know when we'll get access to them?

**UPDATE:** Heres a direct link to the API list => [**New WP7 APIs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202995.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Among other updates (like Silverlight 4 support), new APIs include:

- Sockets
- Support for background agents
- Multitasking
- Clipboard
- Direct access to camera streams
- Silverlight/XNA interop
- Support for Live Tasks
- Local database support (SQLCE)
- Access to the compass and gyroscope
- General sensor API
- VideoFormat
- ElevatedPermissions
- AutomationEvent
- BackgroundAudio
- InteropServices
- IDataObject
- TextComposition
- RichTextBox support

[Here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dennisdel/5629482537/in/set-72157626490620508) is a list of APIs (in a picture) that was shown at the MIX11 keynote.

Comment: No Designer support for RichTextBox . Would expect it to be part of the toolbox in the next update .

Answer (score 6):

The Mango tools are slated for release in May. Voting on Mango build access being available to dev devices prior to consumer release in Fall is taking place [here](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1712977-provide-early-beta-of-new-os-updates-to-developers?ref=title) (among other feature requests).

**Keynote 2**

The 1500 API mention came from Scott Gu in his Mix 11 Keynote 2 linked below. If you track forward to 1:06:55 you can see a slide (referenced in Dennis's answer) which gives a snapshot of some of these and listen to Scott's commentary.

- [MIX11 Day 2 Keynotes | MIX11 |
  Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/mix/mix11/key02)

The first 1 hour, 23 minutes is all Windows Phone goodness.

In essence they are made of APIs to support new capabilities on the phone and APIs that come from the transition from Silverlight 3 to Silverlight 4 as Dennis and Derek advise.

**Breakout Sessions**

More specifics are available throughout the Mix 11 breakout sessions, which are searchable and downloadable here.

- [MIX11 | Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11)

In particular, I would draw your attention to these sessions which expand further on the high level information presented in the keynote and at the end of the first, @AndrewClinick overviews all of the Phone related breakout sessions for you to consider watching.

1. [What’s Coming Next to the Windows Phone Application Platform | MIX11 |
   Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/DVC14)
2. [What’s New for Windows Phone
   Development with Silverlight? | MIX11
   | Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/DVC15)
3. [What’s New for Windows Phone
   Development with the XNA Framework? |
   MIX11 | Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/DVC16)

Remember to rate and comment for speaker feedback :)

**Updates and Details via Twitter**

I've forwarded many of the standout announcements to the community from the keynote and detailed breakout sessions via twitter below.

[Twitter / Search - from:mickndev #wp7dev #mix11](http://twitter.com/#!/search/from%3amickndev%20#wp7dev%20#mix11) or here if twitter search is clogged up when you search: [Mick N (MickNDev) on Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/MickNDev)

I'll continue to share these details with the developer community via twitter as they surface.

[Tweetdeck is a great hands off way to follow the activity](http://www.tweetdeck.com/).

It takes about 1 minute to signup on twitter if you haven't already [here](https://twitter.com/signup).

Answer (score 0):

The updated tools should be available in May (as detailed at MIX) I believe, though some sessions have talked about July for some bits. A lot of the new APIs will come from moving to Silverlight 4 from Silverlight 3. You can catch up on everything that was announced at MIX by watching the sessions at http://live.visitmix.com/mix11